# function call within a vue js v-for directive makes the loop run into an infinite loop and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this template:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-for="report in reports">
        <div class="map" v-bind:id="mapID = report.started.toUpperCase()" v-text="report.started">
        {{hello(mapID)}}

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this model:

```
<script>
import addmap from '../components/addmap';
export default {

    data: function(){
        return {
            reports: [],
            mapid: "",
            map_id: ''
        }
    },

    mounted: function(){
        this.mapID = this.map_id;
        this.allReport()    
    },

    components: {
        'addmap': addmap
    },

    computed: {
        mapID: {
            get: function(){
                return this.map_id;
            },

            set: function(newValue){
                this.map_id = newValue.toUpperCase();
            }
        }   
    },

    methods: {
        hello: function(val){
            console.log(val)    
        },
        allReport: function(){
            axios.get('/reports').then(response => {
                this.reports = response.data
            });
        }
    }
```

}

Whenever I load this view, it report an infinite loop in the console, and I don't know why.

When I print just text it works fine, but whenever I try to call a function on each loop, it reports an infinite loop.

I don't know why this happens and any possible recommendation or suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are overriding the report variable with the inner loop. Why do you have 2 nested loops over `reports`?

Comment: Sorry, the nested loop was a comment. Was trying something.

Comment: `reports` is an object, NOT an array? You can't loop objects with v-for. Also, you should supply unique `key` for `v-for` items.

Comment: Try to loop like this, if it is an object: `v-for="(value, key) in reports`, link: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-v-for

Comment: The `hello(mapID)` does not execute. It's suppose to print to the console. Ordinarily, the `<div>` works well, but the `hello(mapID)` which is suppose to print to the console does not work, instead it prints `You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.`. I don't know why this happens.  Is it that I can't call a function like that? or maybe something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
v-bind:id="mapID = report.started.toUpperCase()"
```

You are changing a reactive data property during rendering, which triggers a re-render, which makes you change the property again, which triggers a re-render, and so on ...

So in short: Don't do this. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, so I'm not sure what to advise instead. Maybe just this?

`v-bind:id="report.started.toUpperCase()"`

Comment: Or just use a computed property.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the Assignment `on v-bind:id`. And it worked.